# Fail when starting PHP5-FPM

Tags: ubuntu, php

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 from 12.04 and now PHP5-FPM fails to start. The error I get when I run /etc/init.d/php5-fpm start is fail. There is nothing being written to log files to give me an indication of what is wrong.

As much as I want to solve this, at this stage I really just want something printed to a log file to give me a clue. This is what I have configured in /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:

```
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/fpm-php.www.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

However this log file is never being written to.

I am running PHP5-fpm version 5.4.9.

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: Permissions on the log file?

Comment: The error_log is only used when php-fpm is running, not when it's trying to start; check the init script to see what could be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of trying to start FPM using your INIT script, try to start it manually. Normally FPM will spit out the error you are looking for to find and resolve the problem.

**Edit 1**

To start FPM manually find and open your INIT script and inside of that file you'll find the start command. For example, mine is like this:

`/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize --fpm-config /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf`

Comment: Thanks guy. You really saved me, after hours of debugging. Simply ran `php5-fpm` and the errors surfaced... and then I killed them!!! ##bwahahaha##.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed in some versions of Ubuntu that calling '/etc/init.d/php5-fpm start' doesn't work while 'service start php5-fpm' does.  That may be why you aren't seeing anything in the logs.